# JWT on PHP side

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm working on a AngularJS / Phonegap / PHP (Zend) project.

I want the users to login via JWT. (this seems the best options since cookies not work). I've found a [tutorial](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/05/json-web-tokens-examples/) to manage it on the angular side

I went googling a lot and found out that google uses the https://github.com/luciferous/jwt version. Also I found a newer one based on that from firebase ( https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt )

(**1**) Which one should I use?

I'm using the `luciferous` now and when I create a token via:

```
$ENV_var = "whatever":
$token = encode("id: 5", $ENV_var);
```

It returns: `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.ImlkOiA1Ig.KtG-rOleZwiDhbMnaLI1vIOczPYUM2Az1KfIeygJ7E0` which is unvalid [here](http://jwt.io/) but valid if I decode it with the same script.

(**2**) Why is this? is this because `jwt.io` is made with/by `Auth0`?

(**3**)Also I don't get when/why I should use the "sign method" instead of encode (below: from github luciferous)

```
  public static function sign($msg, $key, $method = 'HS256')
    {
        $methods = array(
            'HS256' => 'sha256',
            'HS384' => 'sha384',
            'HS512' => 'sha512',
        );
        if (empty($methods[$method])) {
            throw new DomainException('Algorithm not supported');
        }
        return hash_hmac($methods[$method], $msg, $key, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) I would recommend using the firebase implementation, since it is maintained more and has composer support.

The payload that is passed into the `encode` method should be an array of "claims" see [here](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#Claims) e.g.

```
$payload = array('sub' => 1, 'iss' => 'example.com');
$secret = 'someSecretKey';

$token = JWT::encode($payload, $secret);
```

2) because the token you are generating is not based on an array or contain any required claims.

3) you should generally use the encode/decode methods as they will call sign internally

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1. Both are fine to use, however the second has got better documentation. I personally prefer to work with https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt.

You said that JWT generated is not valid. I have tested it and it worked (it got decoded correctly), just make sure to use correct algorithm "HS256" and your secret.

Ad 2. This question is not clear, can you please clarify?

Ad 3. Encode method of that class calls sign. You don't have to call sign yourself, just encode.